Tkinter PhotoImage is returning 'pyimage1' instead of the actual image in treeview row In ttk treeview python is showing pyimage1 instead of image
this part of code is not showing image in the table how can i solve this issue
def show_table():
    """Fetches data from the 'admissions' table and displays it in a Tkinter window."""
    conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM admissions')
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    # Create a new Tkinter window for displaying the table
    table_window = tk.Frame(root, bg="lightblue", padx=10, pady=10)
    table_window.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    # Create a Treeview widget for displaying data with column headers
    table = ttk.Treeview(table_window, columns=('name', 'roll_number', 'standard', 'date_of_admission',
                                               'address', 'mobile_number', 'adharcard', 'image_filename'),show='headings')
   
    # table.configure(rowheight=75)  # Adjust height as needed (consider image size + padding)

     # Adjust column widths as needed
    table.column('name', width=150)
    table.column('roll_number', width=100)
    table.column('standard', width=100)
    table.column('date_of_admission', width=150)
    table.column('address', width=250)
    table.column('mobile_number', width=100)
    table.column('adharcard', width=150)
    table.column('image_filename', width=200)

    table.heading('name', text='Name')
    table.heading('roll_number', text='Roll Number')
    table.heading('standard', text='Standard')
    table.heading('date_of_admission', text='Date of Admission')
    table.heading('address', text='Address')
    table.heading('mobile_number', text='Mobile Number')
    table.heading('adharcard', text='Adharcard')
    table.heading('image_filename', text='Image Filename')

    

    # Insert data into the Treeview
    # for row in data:
    #     image = load_image(row[7])  # Access the image filename in the last column (index 7)
    #     table.insert('', tk.END, values=row[:7] + (image,))  
    
    for row in data:
        photo = load_image(row[7])
        if photo:  # Or your image display method
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=row[:7] + (photo,))  # Include image view
        else:
            # Handle cases where image loading fails (optional)
            placeholder_text = "Image Unavailable"
            table.insert('', tk.END, values=row[:7] + (placeholder_text,))  # Use placeholder
        
    table.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

i tried every think also taking help from gemini and other tools but not able to solve this issue so can someone please help me with this problem

You can't insert images into a tree view, except to the left of the row label. All other columns can only contain text. The reason you see "pyimage1" is because that's the string representation of the image object.
